# TTFB very slow - PDO MSSQL

Tags: php, sql, http

As you can see in the following image

[image]

TTFB is getting about 15 minutes, it doesn't seems to be `httpd` or `mysqld` services (I restarted them) and also `reboot` the server, but still doesn't change nothing.

I found that this problem is occuring on every system that uses `PDO_MSSQL`

```
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MSSQL"
resources.db.params.pdoType = "dblib"
```

There was any changes on that driver recently?

Comment: I can't see anything in that image. The text is way too small. What does it say?

Comment: You can right-click it and open in a new tab.

Comment: TTFB it is "Time To First Byte" i.e. how long it takes for your script to reply. The problem inside your script.

Comment: I rolled back the script to when it didn't have the problem. Maybe any aftermath?

Comment: There is no script source in your question. Probably some DB query takes too long

Comment: Even if I rolled back all the code to when it was normal?